# Unique Application Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web-services, authentication

I am creating a web service to allow application developers (A.K.A. My friends) to query my database. The thing is, as a security constraint I want to be able to track each user. I am in the process of creating a unique app ID like in FaceBook or Google maps.

The developer must submit a username and email address, and when they click generate a unique key will be generated. The thing is, the database must first be checked if the user/email already exists and also check if the key is already generated (pseudo-random generation protection).

To use the webservice the user will have to enter something like:

> webservice.Authenticate('app key here');

to authenticate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was looking at GUID generation. Is it truly unique or is it a pseduo-random number?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?  This sounds like you've got a good plan...

Comment: GUID are almost truly unique.  Okay, so you may get a clash, but the chance of this is so minultly small, its really not worth thinking about, and if you're that worried about a clash, try create another Guid and try again (If you get 2 clashes in a row, write in to Microsoft with your log data).  We genreate several million Guids an da from a single server and have never had a clash.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that you can generate something like a million per second for the life of the universe and the likelihood of a collision is less than 50%.  my numbers may be a little off, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell `Guid.NewGuid()` should be sufficient.

Comment: yeah i just did some more reading and found this method useful. Did a while loop and generated about 20 mill and still didn't get a clash

Comment: @ferronrsmith: You'd probably need to let that loop run for a few hundred years before you hit any statistical likelihood of a clash.

Answer (score 2):

If you go with the GUID solution - you can always make sure it is unique by querying the database. If it isn't unique - just generate a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Make a string out of a salt, the username, and the email address. Then make a hash (MD5 or SHA1) from that string. The salt can simply be userid, or it could be something else, as long as it isn't known to the user.

GUID is fine but it's probably overkill in this situation. Are you going to have billions of users? You could probably get by with a random number between 1 and 1,000,000. Then make sure you disable login after x number of failed attempts, where x is between 3 and 6.

Comment: billion of users, LOL. At most it will be about 200 thousand

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your application and the number of users a Guid may not be the best choice unless you know how to handle them.  Most often I have seen these used as strings, which only increases your storage requirement and slows down your comparison routines.  A string comparison of a guid on a match has to scan all 36 characters.  Way overkill for data which is just stored in hex format.  Its better to save the GUID as an array of integers...you reduce the search while at the same time reducing the storage requirements.

If you only have a few thousand records, then guid as string is probably not going to matter much.  But if your programming for scale, and that scale is large, then proper adjustments now will save you the pain of doing it later.

IF you are doing joins on tables, use an integer identity to do the join, not the guid (for the same reasons already mentioned).

Comment: at most i'll have about 200 thousand. I was was thinking of saving them as an array of integers, but what the heck. It ain't that much record and if needs be i can always change the routine

Answer (score 0):

Typical authentication consists on an identity (a name) and a secret (a password). You are designing an authentication scheme consisting on only a secret, ie. the password (in form of a guid). The problem with this approach (ie. not separating identity from password) is that the user cannot change the password if compromised, because the password *is* their identity.

What Maps API key and similar keys are something else: they are claims signed by the service provider. For example the registered domain from where your app is calling the Maps API. The Generate key accepts a domain you submit, will sign that domain name with a private key of the service and present you with the publis signature. When accessing the API you must present the signature (the API key) that prooves you have signed up and agreed to the terms of service. The other part of the verification (the domain your app is running from, in other words the 'claim') is detected automatically by JavaScript.

I'm by no means an expert on Maps API and I may had got some parts off, but this is typically how things are implemented. I would suggest against using a guid as an obfuscated application ID as it doesn't provide much value: a leaked guid can be used by anybody and you cannot verify any claim using a guid. Think about what are you trying to protect, or just go with an established scheme like OpenId or something.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu the GUID key that is generated wil lbe place in the database along with the person's name, email, (and domain name if we wish). When a user tries to retrieve information the data in the db, that's the GUID, will be validated. I plan to write a stored proc that does further encryption (nothing too extreme). the value stored in the db will be checked along with domain, if these does not match the result set returns null. simple. Its nothing advance, just some fooling around me and some friends doing till school starts back. Anyways thanks for the tip